# Multiple NVL() alternative - first not null parameter

Tags: sql, oracle11g, nvl

Currently I have something like that:

```
NVL(COL1, NVL(COL2, NVL(COL3, NVL(COL4, NVL(COL5, COL6)))))
```

Is in Oracle 11gR2 any function that returns first `NOT NULL` parameter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for [`COALESCE()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm)?

Note that `COALESCE()` is supported on almost all khown databases: Oracle, PostgreSQL, MySQL, MSSQL, SQLite.

Answer (score 3):

Use [**COALESCE()**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm) function , it returns first non null value in expression list.

```
SELECT COALESCE(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6)
FrOM tableName
```